# Symfony2: Questions about forms and validation

Tags: validation, symfony

I have multistage user signup and I seem to be missing something.

I have a user entity and some other data embedded in the form which I want to collect as well.  For the sake of an example we will say User has name and email and these map to fields on the user entity.  On the same form I also have device data as a hidden field.

On my User entity i have a validation group 'plan' so when I submit I do something like this:

```
<?php
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user, array('validation_groups' => array('plan'))
    ->add('name')
    ->add('email')
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request)
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $user = $form->getData();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
} else {
    return $this->render('myform.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

This is mostly rough psuedocode but now when I call $form->getData() or $request->request->all(), device_data is stripped out and no where to be found.  I can get around this by not passing $user into createFormBuilder as the first argument but then my validation group doesn't seem to happen because it is bound to the user entity.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: can you post your twig too?

Comment: I just figured out why the code itself wasn't working, this is sort of a cooked example, the real one was dealing with credit card processing and ajax submission and was fairly complicated to post here so that is why I cooked the example up.  I should have checked the example first though it would have helped me find this solution quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew's answer is good but if you want to perform "direct validation" (through `$form->isValid()` method) you would prefer to use something like this

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user, array('validation_groups' => array('plan'))
               ->add('name')
               ->add('email')
               ->add('agree','checkbox', array('mapped' => false, 'constraints' => array(new NotBlank()))
               ->getForm();
```

where `agree` field, for instance, that is a checkbox that you have to check like "accept terms and conditions" to move on.

`mapped => false` is telling to `createFormBuilder` to don't associate that field with an entity field as it will not be present

Comment: Yea in my case I didn't need to validate the data, just pass it on to an external service for some processing but I think your answer is valid as well.

Comment: @AndrewRevak: I think that's the better way as you can reuse the code and keep it into the same class

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like the problem wasn't exactly as I descried, the correct solution which I had known beforehand is ->add('fieldname', null, array( 'mapped' => false )), however this was not working for me due to an implementation detail and using the DomCrawler.

You can then access the unmapped fields via the request object.

```
$request->request->get('form[fieldname]')
```